# Checking the availability of a username in asp.net using ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am having following textbox in my aasp.net page. And user enters any username in it and I want ajax to check the availability and show the success or failure message in the label as the user leaves the text box.

```
 UserName<asp:Label ID="usernamelbl" runat="server"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID ="usernametxt" runat="server" CssClass="twitterStyleTextbox"></asp:TextBox><br />
```

thats how I am using the ajax

```
function result() {
             var username = "<%=usernametxt%>";
             var result = "<%usernamelbl%>";// here i am getting an error on usernamelbl
             var jsonText = JSON.stringify({ list: username });
             //array = +jsonText;
             $.ajax({
                 url: "staffregistration.aspx/Test", type: "POST", dataType: "json",
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 data: jsonText,
                 success: function (data) {
                     if (data == username) {
                         result = "username available"
                     }
                     else {
                         result = "username not avilable"
                     }},
                 error: function () { alert("its not working"); }
             });
             return false;
         }
```

and thats how i am interacting with the aspx

```
public static string Test(string username)
{
    string conString = @"user id=ejaz;password=ejaz;persistsecurityinfo=True;server=localhost;database=geospatialdb";
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(conString);
    MySqlDataReader reader = null;

    conn.Open();
    MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("select owner_id from owner where owner_username = '" + usernametxt.Text + "';", conn);


    reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    username = reader[0].ToString();
    return username;
}
```

Comment: And you give us as much as the textbox itself? Generous..

Comment: have you tried any ajax at all? If so, post that too

Comment: Actually, I have been trying it with simple js but couldn't do it. So, if I would have used that in my question that wouldn't have actually help as I want something totally different from that.

Comment: ok lemme post whatever I have been trying.

Comment: I have updated my question, just a proof that I tried :D

Comment: Did you try my solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you can detect the change in usernametxt using JavaScript through `onChange` event and Ajax using WebMethods.

**ASPX Page:** Make sure to set EnablePageMethods = true in the ScriptManager object.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="usernameupdatepanel">
    <ContentTemplate>
        UserName <asp:Label ID="usernamelbl" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID ="usernametxt" 
             runat="server" CssClass="twitterStyleTextbox" 
             OnChange="CheckUserName(this)" ></asp:TextBox><br />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function CheckUserName(oName) 
{
    PageMethods.UserNameChecker(oName.value, OnSucceeded); 
}

function OnSucceeded(result, userContext, methodName) 
{   
    lbl = document.getElementById('<%=usernamelbl.ClientID %>'); 

    if (methodName == "UserNameChecker") 
    { 
        if (result == true) 
        { 
            lbl.innerHTML = 'username not available'; 
            lbl.style.color = "red"; 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            lbl.innerHTML = 'username available'; 
            lbl.style.color = "green"; 
        } 
    } 
}
```

**C# Code-Behind:** You can call a WebMethod to check if the new selected filename exists in the DB:

You need to reference the following:

```
using System.Web.Services;
```

Then add the following method and make sure you put `[WebMethod]` before method declaration:

```
[WebMethod]
public static bool UserNameChecker(string newUserName)
{
    string conString = @"user id=ejaz;password=ejaz;persistsecurityinfo=True;server=localhost;database=geospatialdb";
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(conString);
    MySqlDataReader reader = null;

    conn.Open();
    MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("select owner_id from owner where owner_username = '" + newUserName + "';", conn);

    object found = command.ExecuteScalar();

    if (found != null)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Thnaks man! I was trying this before but it didn't work. But this was cool ;)

Answer (score 0):

In a more simple way, just add the scriptmangaer tag and the update panel, then you add the textbox.
Note: Don't forget to set autopostback to true and add an event i.e OnTextChanged event and its handler

```
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" TextMode="Email" OnTextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="" ></asp:Label>   
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

The event handler

```
 protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //your logic 
        }
```